# Summarise transactions fulfilling a criterion in a sliding window

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

We have a table of transactions

```
set.seed(1)
X <- data.table(id = 1:10, 
                time = c(1,2,5,6,9,12,14,20,21,23),
                val = sample(0.1*10^(1:4), 10, replace=TRUE),
                code = sample(c('A','A','C','B'), 10, replace=TRUE)
                )


    id time  val code
 1:  1    1   10    A
 2:  2    2   10    A
 3:  3    5  100    C
 4:  4    6 1000    A
 5:  5    9    1    B
 6:  6   12 1000    A
 7:  7   14 1000    C
 8:  8   20  100    B
 9:  9   21  100    A
10: 10   23    1    B
```

For each row I want to count occurrences of `code == 'A'` along with the sum of `val` for previous rows where `previous_row$time  >= current_row$time - 3`
I.e. the expected result should be

```
    id time  val code count_A_within_3 sum_a_within_3
 1:  1    1   10    A                1             10
 2:  2    2   10    A                2             20
 3:  3    5  100    C                1             10
 4:  4    6 1000    A                1           1000
 5:  5    9    1    B                1           1000
 6:  6   12 1000    A                1           1000
 7:  7   14 1000    C                1           1000
 8:  8   20  100    B                0              0
 9:  9   21  100    A                1            100
10: 10   23    1    B                1            100
```

Is this possible to calculate efficiently using `data.table` or `dplyr`?

The real dataset contains ~1M groups where this operation should be performed within each group. Number of rows in each group range from 1 to 1000. An imperative solution (for loop with nested ifs and state-variables) is doable but very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using non-equi joins from the latest devel version (1.9.7+):

```
X[, prev.time := time - 3]

X[, c("count_A_within_3", "sum_a_within_3") :=
      X[X, on = .(time >= prev.time, time <= time),
        .(sum(code == "A"), sum(val[code == "A"])), by = .EACHI][, .(V1, V2)]]
X
#    id time  val code prev.time count_A_within_3 sum_a_within_3
# 1:  1    1   10    A        -2                1             10
# 2:  2    2   10    A        -1                2             20
# 3:  3    5  100    C         2                1             10
# 4:  4    6 1000    A         3                1           1000
# 5:  5    9    1    B         6                1           1000
# 6:  6   12 1000    A         9                1           1000
# 7:  7   14 1000    C        11                1           1000
# 8:  8   20  100    B        17                0              0
# 9:  9   21  100    A        18                1            100
#10: 10   23    1    B        20                1            100
```

You may want to replace the inner two `X`'s with `.SD` for more robust code; I only left it as `X` for clarity/ease of understanding how it works.

Comment: Would rewriting using .SD remove the repetition of the "code == 'A'"? The real world problem has multiple conditions, e.g. " col_3 %in% lookup_vector & col_4 != 123 & between(col_5, 50, 90)"

Comment: If you only have one (complicated) condition, you can always filter it upfront: `... := X[your_complicated_condition; e.g. code == "A"][X, on = ...`; another option is doing `..., {cond = code == "A"; .(sum(cond), sum(val[cond]))}, ...`

Comment: Is it possible to optimise for execution time? The simple condition (e.g. code == "A") took  ~70 seconds, but a more complex condition  ~1h on my 22M rows 1M groups dataset.

Comment: I added "cond = code == "A""  to X and used a simple "cond==TRUE", this brings back the execution time to ~60s.